# FocusEvent how to figure out it has been triggered through mouse or tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have some code which has some conditional branches if the FocusEvent has been triggered through a mouseclick outside of the input-box or if it has been tabbed out. It's pretty messy JS-Legacy code and I only have time to apply a hotfix here.

Doc for FocusEvent: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FocusEvent

Unlike the Click event the FocusEvent does not have any informations about buttons pressed during the event triggering.

Does anybody has an idea how I can get this information? Via Google I only found workarounds - but I just can't believe that this FocusEvent has a way to receive the button pressed out of the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*FocusEvent* is clearly described as an experimental technology in the doc you linked. So what you ask may be added in the future. But for now it looks like you have no other choice but to use a workaround.

I made one to try:

```js
var clickWhileFocused = false;

$("#testInput").on("tabbedOut", function () {
  console.log("tabbedOut");
});

$("#testInput").on("clickedOut", function () {
  console.log("clickedOut");
});

$(document).on("mousedown", function (e) {
  if($("#testInput").is(":focus") && e.target.id != "testInput") {
    $("#testInput").trigger("clickedOut");
    clickWhileFocused = true;
  }
});

$("#testInput").on("focusout", function () {
  if(!clickWhileFocused) {
    $("#testInput").trigger("tabbedOut");
  }
  
  clickWhileFocused = false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"/>
<input id="testInput" type="text" placeholder="#testInput"/>
<input type="text"/>
```

Comment: Ok thanks for your advice. BTW I found a nice library which logs key/button events globally so you can check at any time anywhere in your code what key has been pressed.

https://github.com/ten1seven/what-input

Comment: Yeh that may be great to actually check for the tab key. In my code I just check if you click out and assume every other `focusout` event is triggered by a tab.